# Angularjs, nested JSON & ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm getting some JSON returned from a server for which I'd like to iterate over the key value pair label and value. I tried to access the values by using the following but I get nothing.

What am I missing for this to work?

HTML :

```
<tr ng-repeat="(label, value) in data[0].[label]">
    <td>{{label}}</td>
    <td>{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

JSON input :

```
"data": {
    "title": {
        "label": "Title",
        "value": "Mr"
    },
}
```

Comment: is that a typo...? data is not an array here...and i guess there is  an extra period after data[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="title in data">
    <td>{{title.label}}</td>
    <td>{{title.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

(Assuming your Json is in a variable like $scope.data)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thank you!